# Webpage header elements should pull-right without using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and working on a small project to bolster my understanding of HTML and CSS that i have learnt.  I have been trying to push my unordered menu list to the right and have failed to do so, below is my code, can anyone help please:

```
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="seller.html">Seller</a></li>
            <li><a href="buyer.html">Buyer</a></li>
            <li><a href="log.html">Log in</a></li>
            <li><a href="sign.html">Sign up</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  display:-webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-pack:center;
}

.big_wrapper{
    width:1100px;
}

header{
    border-bottom:2px solid blue;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px;

}

header>ul>li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 5px;
}

header>ul>li>a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`header ul { text-align: right; }`

adding this in css should help.

Comment: let me try it and i will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `text-align: right;` on `header ul``

```
header{

    margin:0;
    padding:2px;
border-bottom:2px solid blue;
}

header ul{
text-align: right;
}

header>ul>li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 5px;
}

header>ul>li>a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

See the result: http://jsfiddle.net/vh3uxfnq/